# bootstrap html equal line spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code with bootstrap library, but the line spacing are not equal, can anyone help me make the line equally spaced?

https://jsfiddle.net/x82tx4hg/

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="menu_dish_name" name="menu_dish[name]" size="30%" type="text" value="Sinagara">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_desc">Desc</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea cols="29%" id="menu_dish_desc" name="menu_dish[desc]"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_price">Price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="menu_dish_price" name="menu_dish[price]" size="30%" type="text" value="2.0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">Associate Addon Groups</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input name="menu_dish[addon_groups][]" type="hidden" value="">
            <select id="menu_dish_addon_groups" multiple="multiple" name="menu_dish[addon_groups][]" size="3" style="width: 32.5%">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Sodas</option>
                <option value="2">Condisment</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_image">Image</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="menu_dish_image" name="menu_dish[image]" type="file">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Equally spaced in what sense?

Comment: Have you tried using Bootstrap's rows?

Comment: Equally spaced vertically @isherwood

Comment: Yeah, start by not using line breaks as formatting tools, then try j0's suggestion.

Comment: @j08691 thanks using row solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to structure your markup better. Most of the form-group css relies on a parent selector like `.form-inline .form-group` or `.nav-bar .form-group`.

Reference the [bootstrap docs and examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) too.

When done right, you should not need the `<br>` tag at all.

---

#### EDIT

Upon looking at this again, you are omitting `<div class="row">`'s between your `col` elements. Look at the [grid syntax](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for more direction.

Answer (score 0):

`.form-group` was not containing its floats. You could make it contain them with:

```
.form-group { overflow: hidden }
```

You’ll also want to take out the spacing `<br>` elements. [Properly spaced example](https://jsfiddle.net/57g1ttad/).

Answer (score 0):

I would take out the breaks and use margins or padding to create the spaces

CSS

```
.col-md-11 .form-group {
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_name">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="menu_dish_name" name="menu_dish[name]" size="30%" type="text" value="Sinagara">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_desc">Desc</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <textarea cols="29%" id="menu_dish_desc" name="menu_dish[desc]"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_price">Price</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="menu_dish_price" name="menu_dish[price]" size="30%" type="text" value="2.0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">Associate Addon Groups</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input name="menu_dish[addon_groups][]" type="hidden" value="">
            <select id="menu_dish_addon_groups" multiple="multiple" name="menu_dish[addon_groups][]" size="3" style="width: 32.5%">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Sodas</option>
                <option value="2">Condisment</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="menu_dish_image">Image</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input id="menu_dish_image" name="menu_dish[image]" type="file">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hk51kctn/